# VBA code to change text in shape that link from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

below is my code that i used  the second code is working but the function on Text's Shape
Dont working well it just show **=LIST!A2** what it need to show is the number from cell A2 in the sheet name list. i try to modified but seem to now working well

thank in adv. for anyhelp

```
 Sub AFRVIS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sp As Shape
    Set ws = Sheet2
    For Each sp In ws.Shapes


         Sheet2.Shapes.Range("Rounded Rectangle 2").FormulaArray = "=LIST!B2"



    Next
End Sub

Sub NoVIS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sp As Shape
    Set ws = Sheet2
    For Each sp In ws.Shapes

         Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 2")).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "=LIST!A2"


    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle 2")).TextFrame.Characters.Text = _
Sheet1.Range("A2")
```

It is solved now.